# Question with reading csv using encoding - ISO-8859-1

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading in a csv file that is being sent by another team weekly.

Previously, my python script had no issue  with reading that file (using pandas).  But with this week's data I got an error "UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 208426: ordinal not in range(128)"

I found another stackoverflow post about checking the csv encoding using chardet (python).  I followed that script and it shows encoding='ascii'.   So I updated my python read_csv as follows:

df = pd.read_csv('file', encoding='ascii')

However, I still get the same error.  Upon further checking stackoverflow I came upon a random post suggesting to use `encoding='ISO-8859-1'`  and it worked.

I tried doing read_csv using `encoding='ISO-8859-1'` on the other csv files that normally do not need encoding, and surprisingly it works on those csv files, too.

I asked the team who sent me the file if they had done any encoding and they said no.

I hope this won't eventually bite my behind.  Would appreciate anyone's input on this.

Comment: it's CSV, so: load it up in a hex editor, or even a good code editor, and find out what's before, at, and after position 208426. Is that real data, or does your file have a corrupted byte?

Comment: Total guess: the files so far contained only characters in the range 0-127. In that case UTF-8, ASCII and Latin-1 are all interchangeable encodings, as they’re the same in that range. Now you got your first file with some character outside that range, and it starts to matter. — Clarify with that other team what encoding they’re sending the file in and are going to continue to send the file in.

Comment: To add to that: ASCII is a seven bit character set, and a true subset of Unicode. However, [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) is an "extended" _eight_ bit character set, of which the first half is ASCII, but everything over 0x7F is (by  definition) _not_ in ASCII, and generally incompatible with Unicode. So you absolutely need to tell `read_cvs` what encoding your file uses.

Answer (score 3):

Every text file has an encoding which describes which bytes translate to which characters. [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) only supports byte values 0-127 and assigns specific characters to those values, which is why byte value 0xA0 (160 decimal) wasn't supported.

[ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) assigns meaning to all 256 bytes, and 0xA0 is a `NO-BREAK SPACE` in that encoding.

If the file came from a Windows computer, the encoding could be any of the legacy ANSI encodings. [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) is common for US and most Western European Windows versions.  0xA0 is still `NO-BREAK SPACE` but other byte values vary, such as 0x80 for the Euro sign (€).

Since ISO-8859-1 won't fail, but may translate bytes to the wrong values, you must look at the non-ASCII characters and see if they make sense in the context of the text file if you don't know the actual encoding.

Examples of differences (`errors='replace'` handles undefined decodings with  �):

```
>>> bytes(range(128,256)).decode('iso-8859-1')
'\x80\x81\x82\x83\x84\x85\x86\x87\x88\x89\x8a\x8b\x8c\x8d\x8e\x8f\x90\x91\x92\x93\x94\x95\x96\x97\x98\x99\x9a\x9b\x9c\x9d\x9e\x9f\xa0¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬\xad®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùúûüýþÿ'
>>> bytes(range(128,256)).decode('windows-1252', errors='replace')
'€�‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š‹Œ�Ž��‘’“”•–—˜™š›œ�žŸ\xa0¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬\xad®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùúûüýþÿ'
>>> bytes(range(128,256)).decode('ascii', errors='replace')
'��������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������'
```

Further reading:

- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)
- [Pragmatic Unicode *~or~* How Do I Stop the Pain?](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain/unipain.html)